# Ubuntu Server Installing PHP 7 WITHOUT Apache

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to get my server re-setup as a Lemp stack

The issue I am now running into is installing PHP 7 **without** Apache, since nGinx will be my webserver.

So, I've added `ppa:ondrej/php`. ran `apt-get update`, and tried to install just php7.0 via `apt-get install php7.0`

`--nodeps` flag does not work, as I am on Ubuntu 15.10

And I am presented with:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 libqdbm14
  php-common php-readline php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json
  php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom php-pear
  php-user-cache
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 libqdbm14
  php php-common php-readline php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json
  php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
```

I **do not want** apache anywhere near my server, so how can I install php7 without it?  Short of compiling from source (as this makes it difficult at best to keep it updated)

Comment: Is compilation an option ? e.g. https://gist.github.com/tronsha/b471dd6d73dc8ebae242

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you just request `php7.0`, it'll install Apache as default. Do `apt-get install php7.0-fpm` and it'll install as FPM instead, leaving something like nginx up to you.

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing (of course with more modules.. but you get the gist :)  )

Comment: This was working perfectly for me up until a few weeks ago until today when I rebuilt my server, and now `php7.0-fpm` will not install via the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo, and gives the error - `Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-fpm'`! :(

Comment: @DaveRix Try `apt-cache search php` and see what packages are there. IIRC the PPA maintainer moved some stuff around.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I've tried that, and only php5-fpm is listed, not the php7 version. I will need to try to contact the maintainer, as all the information I can find points to the same set of instructions, which are currently not working.

Comment: You should use `sudo apt install php8.0-fpm` on Linux PHP 8 installation now.

Comment: Use the meta package with `sudo apt install php-fpm` if you want to keep it meta ;-)

Answer (score 29):

Use the command:

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

It will require the php7.2 dependencies in strict mode (**WITHOUT apache2**).

Comment: Will it install nginx?

Comment: @LucasBustamante No, you have to install that separately and configure php for that

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer because it does install php without apache!

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I managed to do this successfully with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli
```

Comment: The answer is confusing, the normal php use is on a website and not on a cmdl. New to php and you are lost with the answer, so -1

Comment: The question is WITHOUT apache. Read the original question. There are many uses where a developer just needs php but not all the rest. At the time I wrote this, it was for a CI/CD server.

Comment: or better yet: `sudo apt install php-cli`

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 20.04, `php 7.4` is the default.
Thus, without adding any PPAs, all you need is

```
apt install php-fpm
```

This will bring in a few libraries, including `php-cli`, but NO apache-related things.

Answer (score 2):

With the following steps you can install any PHP version you want, just replace 7.4 with your desired version.

Also I am suggesting to install the **cli** package because I assume you dont want to have **fpm** installed. Otherwise you can install php7.4-fpm instead.

Install ppa:ondrej/php repositories

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Install PHP

```
sudo apt install php7.4-cli
```

You will get the following:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php-common php7.4-common php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline
```